# How to put text float around image like some newspapers' format using CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, word-wrap

I want my image wrapping with text align like this

```
<html>

text text text text text <br>
text text text text text <br>
______________    text text text <br>
image    | text text text <br>
image    | text text text <br>
image    | text text text <br>
___________|  text text text (end)
</html>
```

I've tried this `< DIV style="text-align:justify; text-justify:newspapers; padding:10px; font-size:1ุpx" > text text text text ....`  but the result comes like this

```
______________ <br>
image    | text text text text<br>
image    | text text text text<br>
image    | text text text text<br>
____________|  text text text text<br>
text text text text text text  
text text text text text text (end)
```

What should I do without manual putting ? (like align text first , then image and final , text) because all images and texts of my website will be fetched from the database.

Answer (score 10):

use Float propert in image and write text normally

Eg

```
<p>
 some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

<img src="some.jpg" style="float:left">

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, all my texts are from the database which I don't know how long each so I am afraid I cannot use your method.

Comment: u can always use it regardless of the length of the text 
like: <p><img><text></p>. If u want image on top and <p><text><img></p> if u want it bottom. As ur figure in question suggest

Answer (score 1):

Use `margin-top` on the floated box.

Answer (score 0):

Use the property align om the image tag ie, `<img src="" alt="" align="left" />`

But still i depends on where the img tag is placed in the html..

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_align.asp

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Are there any css commands i.e. text-justify:xxxx to set the format like the first one I want ?

Comment: @pfau - not what i know of sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I did this inside a wordpress loop, making use of the "more tag" in my post. as the tag divides the content it is easy to make the float around whatever you like. In my case it is the posts title and excerpt.
I did make use of the wpauto filter, for kicking the formatting tags, coming from wordpress.
My css file looks like:

```css
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #ff5800;
}
#page {
width: 45%;
min-width: 230px;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid white;
}
.content{
margin:10px;
background-color: #ff5800;
text-align: justify;
padding: 6px;
}
.title{
font-family: Freestyle Script;
color: black;
background-color: #fff;
min-width: 200px;
width: 75%;
font-size: 3em;
line-height: 50px;
vertical-align: middle;
float:left;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-top: 12px;
text-align: center;
margin-left: -6px;
margin-right: 6px;
}
.excerpt{
font-family: Freestyle Script;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
background-color: #fff;
min-width: 200px;
width: 75%;
font-size: 2.2em;
line-height: 32px;
float:left;
clear: both;
margin-left: -6px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
text-align: center;margin-right: 6px;
}
```

And i let this index.php be served out of a blogs subdirectory:

```html
<?php
  // get the blog content
  define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
  require('../wp-blog-header.php');
  query_posts('showposts=1' );
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('term_description','wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content','wpautop');
function remove_images( $content ) {
   $postOutput = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', $content);
   return $postOutput;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_images', 100 );
?>
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); 
// split content at the more tag and return an array
function split_content() {
    global $more;
    $more = true;
        $content = preg_split('/<span id="more-\d+"><\/span>/i', get_the_content('more'));
    for($c = 0, $csize = count($content); $c < $csize; $c++) {
        $content[$c] = apply_filters('the_content', $content[$c]);
    }
    return $content;
}
?>
<div id="page">
<div class="content">
<?php
    // the_content();
    // split content into array
        $content = split_content();

    // output first content section in column1
        echo array_shift($content);
?>
   // the object where the float happens
 <div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
 <div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
   // you wont recognize a gap inbetween the splittet surounding
  
<?php
$link = get_permalink();
 // output remaining content sections in column2
        echo implode($content), ' <a href="', ($link), '">to the mainsite...</a>';
?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
 
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Remember making use of the "more tag" inside your post, or the effect won't work. Good chances of a live preview is here: [Floating around](http://em.kione.de/template/)